# How to clear captured stdout/stderr in between of multiple assert statements

Tags: python, pytest

I have some tests with assertions in loop, each assertion is kinda like separate test and  I don't want previous assertions' output to pollute error logs of current failed assertion.

```py
def test_foos(captured):
    foos = []  # some data
    for foo, bar in foos:
        captured.clear()
        assert logic(foo) == bar
```

I have found [`caplog.clear`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/logging.html) but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `pytest` will finish test execution after first failed assertion so you will see only one error log.

Comment: @Sanyash yeah, there will be one error log but it will contain output from all previous `logic` calls because they are in the same scope as failed assert

Comment: Oh, you meant output of `logic` calls... It wasn't clear. Glad that you got an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Parametrize your test](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html). Pass the `foos` as parameter and pytest will  run the test `assert` line multiple times, recording success/failure as if each were a separate test.

```
import pytest

testdata = [
    (3,9),
    (4,16),
    (5,25)
]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("x,expected", testdata)
def test_foos(x, expected):
    assert logic(foo) == bar # in the example, say logic squares the input
```

Comment: this is even better than what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answer that in your case, using `pytest.mark.parametrize` is the best approach. However, for completeness, you *are* able to clear captured output with the [`capsys`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#capsys) fixture.

Example:

```py
def logic(letter):
    print("Handling letter", letter)
    return letter.isupper()

def test_foo():
    letters = ["A", "b", "c"]
    for letter in letters:
        assert logic(letter)
```

The test will fail at `"b"` and print:

```
----------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
Handling letter A
Handling letter b
```

To prevent the output from (successfully) handling `"A"`, we can add `capsys` to the arguments and use `capsys.readouterr` to clear the buffer in between:

```py
def test_foo(capsys):
    letters = ["A", "b", "c"]
    for letter in letters:
        assert logic(letter)
        capsys.readouterr()
```

Now, the tests still fail at `"b"`, but only print:

```
----------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
Handling letter b
```