# How to access captured stdout/stderr in pytest outside of test function, during collection?

Tags: python, pytest, stdout

I have the following particular question about pytest. During collection, stdout is filled with a lot of useless, maybe sensitive information (in the following example abstracted by `print(1)`). Therefore, I don't want this information to show up in pytest's "Captured stdout" output, in case an error happens during collection (in the following example a `ZeroDivisionError`). However, there is also useful information in stdout (in the following example abstracted by `print(2)`). So my idea was to just access stdout in between.

Inside a test function, I can use the `capsys` fixture to access the captured stdout as described [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html) in the pytest docs. What can I use in my case **outside a test function**, during collection?

Example `test.py`, even without any actual test functions:

```py
print(1)
# access stdout here
print(2)
1/0 # arbitrary error
```

Call to pytest:

```
$ python3 -m pytest test.py 
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.7, pytest-4.5.0, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.11.0
rootdir: /home/user/Documents
collected 0 items / 1 errors                                                   

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
___________________________ ERROR collecting test.py ___________________________
test.py:4: in <module>
    1/0
E   ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
------------------------------- Captured stdout --------------------------------
1
2
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================== 1 error in 0.07 seconds ============================
```

As you can see, both `1` and `2` are captured. I want to clear stdout in between, so only `2` will show up. I mean, the captured stdout has to be stored by pytest somewhere, right? I just don't know how to access it, to clear it.

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to achieve by clearing the output of a particular print function? This is a strange thing you are requesting and I doubt there are very many valid use cases. What's so bad about `1` showing up in the output?

Comment: Try these [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python)

Comment: How about this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56187165/how-to-clear-captured-stdout-stderr-in-pytest)?

Comment: Can you just [capture stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python) then dispose or keep it as you wish?